# Return a Type of a specific interface?

Tags: c#, types

Suppose there's a interface `IView` where several implementations exist.
Now there are multiple other classes that has the following property:

```
public Type ViewType { get; }
```

**I want to ensure that the returned Type is of type `IView`.

Is there any way to achieve this? (like `where returnvalue: IView`)**

Please note that the property does *not* return a instance of `IView`.
If so there would be this way:
`public T GetView<T>() where T: IView {  }`

The other way would be to check the returned type at any place where the property is called - but that's a lot of code for the same check.

Comment: I would not expect the property to return an instance of `IView` but a type *implementing* `IView`.. so what are you really asking?

Comment: The question is't very clear, but I think you can make your class generic with restriction to generic parameter to be IView. And then return typeof(T).

Comment: @LewsTherin: Yes! Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: @LewsTherin makes a good point - your limiting the types for T to those which implement IView, therefore your return type is whatever T is

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: The problem is that multiple instances of the class are used together in some lists. But that would no longer be possible with a generic class using different `<T>`s.

Comment: How are you defining the value to return - you only have a get defined. You could use the setter to validate the type implements IView

Comment: @joe that's easy, make a non-generic abstract base class.

Answer (score 1):

Both your solutions immediately sprang to mind.

Perhaps you could alleviate the repetition of checking the returned type by adding a helper method:

```
public bool ViewImplementsIView()
{
    return typeof(this.ViewType).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IView));
}
```

That encapsulates the test into your class so you've reduced the amount of validation needed elsewhere - potentially, you could even throw an exception on your getter if this returns false.

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
bool ImplementsIView(object t)
{
   return typeof(IView).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(t.GetType()));
}
```

**update**

```
 bool ImplementsIView(Type t)
    {
       return typeof(IView).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(t));
    }
```

Comment: Well, `t` is a instance, but I asked how to ensure that a `Type` object has a interface.